# xamarin send large files via rest

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm getting a `http error response 422` from the server and not sure if it is front end or backend with problem. So if you can see anything wrong with call please let me know. :)

```
    public void AddFileToTask(int taskId, byte [] picture, NSDictionary   imageMetadata, Action<List<APFile>> callback)
    {

        var request = new RestRequest("/api/files");
        request.AddParameter("metadata", imageMetadata, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddFile("file",picture, new Guid().ToString()+".jpg");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        request.Method = Method.POST;
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
            if(response.ErrorException != null || response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                const string message = "Error retrieving response.  Check inner details for more info.";
                var responseException = new ApplicationException(message, response.ErrorException);
                throw responseException;
            } else {
                List<APFile> responseFiles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<APFile>>(response.Content, deserializationSettings);
                callback(responseFiles);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Off course the problem was with the back end. Code is correct !

Comment: yeah, but what's the fix?